# preview page signup redirecting to another static page error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-routing

I have a preview page up with a form that takes in emails(@premails). I've created a model & migration for this.

I have a pages controller with a Home, About & Contact actions and corresponding views.

After they submit their email on the Home page, I want to redirect them to a static About page. I have not been able to achieve this.

this is my pages controller:

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController

    def home
        @premail = Premail.new
        if @premail.save
            redirect_to about_path
        else
            render home_path
        end
    end

    def about
    end


end
```

But when I open my localhost with this code I get:

```
NameError in PagesController#home
undefined local variable or method `about_path' for #<PagesController:0x337ac40>
```

How can I make this happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your case, use:

```
    if @premail.save
        redirect_to :action => :about
    end
```

`else` is not needed here, since by default Rails would render `app/views/pages/home.html.erb`, be sure you have this file.

Also when you redirect to `about`, you will need `app/views/pages/about.html.erb` file to be present.

## Update

Seems you don't have [this route](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#bound-parameters) in `config/routes.rb`, for Rails 3.x:

```
match ':controller(/:action(/:id))'
```

In Rails 4:

```
match ':controller(/:action(/:id))', :via => [:get , :post]
```

If you are planning to just answer to get, i.e. there are nor forms posting to controllers:

```
get ':controller(/:action(/:id))'
```

This will detect routes like `localhost:3000/asd/qwe/1` and:

1. Use `asd` as controller `AsdController`
2. Use `qwe` as action:

   ```
   class AsdController
     def qwe; end
   ```
3. `params[:id]` would be equal to 1.
4. `()` means optional, for example if you go in your browser to `localhost:3000/asd`, Rails would call `Asd#index`, i.e.:

   ```
   class AsdController
     def index
       # whatever you have here
     end
   ```

Comment: I have this 'resources  :pages' does this not work? Is there a better way to do this without having to do this, I've heard that using 'resources' syntax is better.. What format could I pass to 'redirect_to' without modifying other code to redirect to the about page?

Comment: I have done all this this and get the following error: No route matches {:action=>"about", :controller=>"pages"}

Comment: Why is this needed? I've never seen this... What does it do?

Comment: BTW this gives me another error: You should not use the `match` method in your router without specifying an HTTP method. If you want to expose your action to both GET and POST, add `via: [:get, :post]` option. If you want to expose your action to GET, use `get` in the router: Instead of: match "controller#action" Do: get "controller#action

Comment: ah right, in Rails 4 generic `match` calls are not allowed, you can change match with get. but if you have a form you could do: `match ':controller...', :via => [:get, :post]`

Comment: Where can I learn more about this? The documentation does a poor job of explaining this I haven't been able to understand why this is needed and how to properly format routing issues

Comment: there is a link in my answer.